# Thinktecture IdentityServer getting started walkthrough error

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server

I am following the Thinktecture IdentityServer walkthrough but I got an error.  [Link to the tutorial](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3/wiki/Getting-started)

I installed both packages with these commands:

```
install-package Microsoft.Owin.Host.Systemweb
install-package Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3 -pre
```

But when I add the Startup class and paste the code inside I get an error at

```
scopes: Scope.StandardScopes
```

saying that

```
Error   1   'Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Models.Scope' does not contain a definition for 'StandardScopes'
```

I downloaded the MVC authentication sample but that project won't build either because two packages their path's are too long. I also downloaded the entire Version 3 and that project does build, but it is entirely different then the other ones, I could start with this and look at all the classes and such and what they do but I would like to do the tutorial as well to learn it step by step. Anybody know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scopes.StandardScopes has become StandardScopes.All in beta 3 - I have fixed the walkthrough. Thanks for reporting!